# Rails - SQL - joins and COALESCE

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an accounts table and an account_logins table. I'm trying to select every account, and then order them by their last login time. So far I have the following:

```
accounts
  .confirmed_visible_with_completed_profile
  .joins(:logins)
  .select('accounts.*, max(account_logins.created_at) as last_sign_in_at')
  .group('accounts.id')
```

This works however if an account has no account_logins associated with it, it's not returned in the query. My SQL is pretty poor but I've found COALESCE through googling, and have tried:

```
accounts
  .confirmed_visible_with_completed_profile
  .joins(:logins)
  .select('accounts.*, COALESCE(max(account_logins.created_at), 0) as last_sign_in_at')
  .group('accounts.id')
```

However this still doesn't return records without an account_login associated. From what I've read `COALESCE(max(account_logins.created_at), 0)` should return 0 if max(account_logins.created_at) is NULL, so I'm confused why this isn't working. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed those values in the join part and so `coalesce` in `select` is useless in this case. `select` is the last operation applied. You need a `left join` to solve your issue

in rails 5 you have `left_joins`

```
accounts
  .confirmed_visible_with_completed_profile
  .left_joins(:logins)
  .select('accounts.*, COALESCE(max(account_logins.created_at), 0) as last_sign_in_at')
  .group('accounts.id')
```

before rails 5

```
accounts
  .confirmed_visible_with_completed_profile
  .joins("LEFT JOIN account_logins ON accounts.id = account_logins.account_id")
  .select('accounts.*, COALESCE(max(account_logins.created_at), 0) as last_sign_in_at')
  .group('accounts.id')
```

you still need `coalesce`. with the `left join` makes sense

Comment: Thanks for explaining - I can see now joins will exclude any records without an account_login before anything else happens - answer works perfectly :)

Comment: We could have some additional fun in rails < 5. `.joins(Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(AccountLogin.arel_table,nil).tap { |j| j.right = j.create_on(Account.arel_table[:id].eq(AccountLogin.arel_table[:account_id]))})`, I just have a huge distaste for String joins :)

Comment: @engineersmnky me too but I've never taken time to learn Arel :D

Comment: @Ursus given your clear experience in ruby, and rails for that matter, I would recommend trying to find time, I know it has really benefited me. The things you can do with `arel` are amazing and integration into traditional `ActiveRecord` queries in a reasonably seamless manner.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, I'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nullif`

```
COALESCE(nullif(max(account_logins.created_at),''), 0)
```